# Ada with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ada, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I downloaded the Netbeans plugin for programming with Ada. However, I don't know, how to link the Eclipse to the Ada platform library. What should link to the IDE? lib,etc,bin ? I don't know what what to do.

Comment: Are you talking about the a general Netbeans, or one specifically designed to work with your Ada compiler? A link might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing the [Ada plugin modules](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Ada) in NetBeans, use `File > New Project` to create a new Ada project. In the `New Ada Application` dialog, click `Manage` to select your installed Ada compiler.

Comment: I found the generated `.gpr` file instructive.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Netbeans or Eclipse, but [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Ada) might be applicable?

Also, further browsing led to [this thread on comp.lang.ada](http://groups.google.it/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_thread/thread/5bcecfde044a119d).