# Can't make Ada work with Xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode, macos, ada, gnat

I've been looking around the web for an hour and I'm just giving up to ask it here...
I've got to work under Ada. I managed to make gnat work as a command line to compile my files.
But I want to be able to have proper projects in Xcode. My problem is that I've found some templates on the to make ada default templates, I've copy pasted them a bit everywhere (/library/developer/ application support etc) but they never appear in the list when I want to create a project.

My other problem is that when I create an empty project and add a .adb file to it I can't compile at all... How do I specify that I should use gnat with it?

I'm sorry for all these questions if they are stupid but I can't find the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternatives that may be of interest: the [Ada plugin modules for NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048096/ada-with-netbeans) and the [Ada 05 Language Module for BBEdit 9.x and TextWrangler 2.x](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jbmatthews/misc/bbedit.html) .

FWIW, templates live in `/Developer/Library/Xcode` in Xcode 3.1.4.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [XCode Ada Plugin from here](http://maxao.free.fr/xcode-ada-plugin/), it looks like it was made to work with Xcode 3.0. You might try downgrading to that and see if you have any better luck.

Personally, my IDE of choice is [Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/), so I can't go into any real detail about XCode past that. I'd suggest talking to the [MacAda mailing list](http://www.macada.org/macada/Contacts.html) if you don't get a good answer here.

Comment: cheers I'm now using ada's plugin for netbeans works perfectly... The only problem is that I can't make the debugger work but it seems that it's an even bigger problem as GDB doesn't work in command line with ada. Anybody has got an idea?

Comment: @charly - Try posting it as another question (if you are still having the problem that is).