# How can I compile/build Ada on Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, gnat

I’m running [Mac OS X v10.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion) with Xcode 4.5.1 with command line tools.

I have just installed [GNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNAT) 2012 [from here](http://libre.adacore.com/download/configurations#).

I installed it using this tutorial:

> Navigate to the directory that contains a file called: doinstall
> Enter: sudo mkdir /usr/loca/gnat You will have to enter your password
> Enter: sudo ./doinstall Press return and y as prompted Update your
> path: sudo export PATH=/usr/local/gnat/bin:$PATH You should now be
> able to compile using the command gnatmake

Everything went fine and I restarted. On my desktop I have file *hello.adb*:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Hello is
begin
    Put_Line ("Hello, World!");
end Hello;
```

And in terminal I navigate to my desktop and execute the `gnatmake hello.adb`. But I get this

```
-bash: gnatmake: command not found
```

But in the terminal, if I execute `info gnat`, I get a very large documentation file.

1. Why can’t I compile *hello.adb*? Is there a way to fix it?
2. Can I create Ada projects and compile/debug within Xcode? I would like to edit the source files using Xcode as the IDE. If so, what type of project shall I use? "external build system" perhaps?
   What could a tutorial be on how to run a [Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) application using Xcode? Video would be great. It is such a pity that Ada has few little resources on the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the path to Ada in a more permanent place. The command you entered in your Terminal only lasts for as long as the terminal is open.

Open the [$HOME/.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file and add

```
export PATH=/usr/local/gnat/bin:$PATH
```

You can open the file from Terminal with either

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

If you're using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (executable `zsh`), place the `export` line in the [$HOME/.zshrc](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) file.

For #2, I can't find an updated Xcode plugin, but if you want an IDE, check out [this top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091088/cant-make-ada-work-with-xcode-3-2).

Comment: Yeyy! You are awesome! just one questions: When I gnatmake hello.adb it creates 2 other files. How can I run hello.adb in the same terminal window? Right now I have to double click on it and it opens in another terminal window which has a white bg.

Comment: @Alex90: I think you can just run `./hello`, where "hello" is whatever executable file you double-click to run. Does that do it?

Comment: yes. I needed to have "./" before the file name. You made my day! Have a nice day you too.

Comment: Re *".bash_profile"*: Do you mean *".bashrc"*?

Comment: OK, the OP *might* have [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*